# How to change instance functionality based on a component of that instance?

Tags: python

I have a function `Character` that is the visual and functional representation of a character on the map. This `Character` has a `CharacterData` component that is the actual character being represented. In some rare cases, the `CharacterData` component has a different idea about how some functionality of the `Character` should work. I was planning to have the `CharacterData` class have some variables with the same name as functions in `Character`, and usually have them set to `None`, but sometimes have them point to a replacement function. This works, but I feel like there must be a better way. Subclassing `CharacterData` does not seem like it fits because `CharacterData` rarely wants to change functionality, and does not need to know anything about `Character`. Subclassing `Character` does not seem like if fits because it doesn't know about the different functionality until it gets `CharacterData`. The class creating `Character` also doesn't necessarily know that `Character`'s functionality needs changing. Below is an example.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, data: CharacterData):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.data = data
        self.move_action = self.move
        if self.data.move_action is not None:
            self.move_action = self.data.move_action  # replace function if component wants different functionality

    def move(self, *args):  # args catches extra selfs
        self.y += 1

    def perform_move(self):
        self.move_action(self)  # Needs to explicitly send self for replacement function

class CharacterData:
    def __init__(self, name, atk, move_action):
        self.name, self.atk = name, atk
        self.move_action = move_action

# Defined elsewhere and passed to CharacterData
def move_action_replacement(*args):
    args[0].x += 1
    args[0].y += 1
```

Comment: "Is there a better way" sounds like you're asking for opinions; perhaps you can take a look at [ask] and see if you can think of a way to make this question more objective? It might get more attention that way.

Comment: It sounds like creating subclasses of `Character` would be the classic way to go. I see you pass an instance of `CharacterData` into each instance of `Character`. Perhaps a factory should examine `data` first and choose the correct class to instantiate.

Comment: @quamrana That almost sounds like the way to go, but may end up with an unwieldy amount of subclasses if some CharacterData X requires changing funcA, Y requires changing funcB,, and Z requires changing both funcA and funcB in the same way as X and Y.

Comment: Yes, it will be exactly the same amount of work as if you were to customise variables in CharacterData. It will only work if you have a fixed number of subclasses to do. (Or if new subclasses are rarely introduced). If you have a very large number of variations, but those variations are driven by a data source, you could programmatically produce variables for `CharacterData`, or even programmatically produce subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood your issue here, so please tell me if I missed the point.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, data: CharacterData):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.data = data

    def _default_move(self):
        self.y += 1

    def move(self):
        if self.data.move_action is not None:
            self.data.move_action(self)
        else:
            self._default_move()

class CharacterData:
    def __init__(self, name, atk, move_action=None):
        self.name, self.atk = name, atk
        self.move_action = move_action

# Defined elsewhere and passed to CharacterData
def move_action_replacement(*args):
    args[0].x += 1
    args[0].y += 1
```

I think the main issue with having "move_action", "perform_move", "move", etc, is that it makes the whole thing very hard to understand. Also with what you wrote if your CharacterData's move_action is changed after the Character's initialisation you won't be able to reflect this change.